# Passing Gridview LinkButton ID to Modal PopUp in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a button like this in my gridview,

`<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkCustDetails" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' OnClick="lnkCustDetails_Click" />`

and I get the id like this:

```
protected void lnkCustDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
    string custID = lb.Text;
    lblCustValue.Text = custID;

    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();   
}
```

My problem is, what can I use instead of having the id in `Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'` because this displays the id of the customer in the linbutton, when I want the link button to display "Details"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to handling commands instead of clicks:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkCustDetails"
                Text='Details'
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>'
                OnCommand="lnkCustDetails_Click" />
```

And to get the id:

```
protected void lnkCustDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
    string custID = lb.CommandArgument;
    lblCustValue.Text = custID;

    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();   
}
```

One note though: I am not sure if you can handle LinkButton's command directly if it lives inside the grid view. You might need to subscribe to grid view's On Command instead - please check.

Comment: @whwuifhwui, just to confirm - you did not need to handle grid view's on command, right?